# How to properly use class as property for another class?

Tags: c#, .net

Here I have this class which is basically a data structure:

```
public class Config
{
    public uint? Release { get; set; }
    public string InstallPath { get; set; }
    public uint? CheckEveryXMinutes { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"(Release: {Release}, InstallPath: {InstallPath}, CheckEveryXMinutes {CheckEveryXMinutes})";
    }
}
```

And I want to use this structure as property of another class like this:

```
public class ConfigRegistry
{
    public Config Result { get; set; }
        
    public ConfigRegistry (string registryKey)
    {
        Result.Release = 0; 
        Console.WriteLine("Read Release from registry: {0}", Result.Release);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting an error at "**Result.Release = 0**" line:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Every reference type like a class must be initialized before you can use it. So use new

Comment: Thanks, Tim! never thought of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add

```
Result = new Config();
```

Comment: Indeed. Two improvement suggestions: (1) You can initialize the class right at the property declaration: `public Config Result { get; set; } = new Config();`. (2) You can remove the public setter: This will only allow users to change individual properties in your Result object, rather than replacing the complete Result instance itself: `public Config Result { get; } = new Config();`.